# How to catch command line output with Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, unix

I want to catch the time when this "done" is outputted in the console, but I am not sure how to do this:

```
var cp = require('child_process');

cp.exec('avconv -strict experimental -i ' + filename + ' ' + tempname + ';' + ' echo done', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
});
```

Tried checking the stdout, but it just brings lots of information about the file.

avconv is a tool for converting files so my goal in here is to check when the converting is done and proceed further on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stdout` **does** return the output from the command. You should try something simpler at first to see if you're actually calling the command correctly.

Try this:

```
child_process.exec('ls', function (err, stdout, stderr){
    if (err) {
        console.log("error: " + err.code);
    }
    console.log(stdout);
});
```

Comment: This works, it brings back the content of the server folder. There fore my version - cp.exec('avconv -strict experimental -i ' + filename + ' ' + tempname + ';' + ' echo done', function(err, stdout, stderr) also works, therefore I am not sure if it outputs when done or in the process of converting the file.

Comment: Why do you need to output 'done' after the code is done? You'll know when `avconv` finishes because you get the callback.

Comment: @funguy [`callback - Function called with the output when process terminates`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)

Comment: I guess, this is what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the time when `exec`'s callback will called

```
var cp = require('child_process');
cp.exec('ls', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
   console.log(new Date())
});
```